# Loading Polymer elements on demand

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to reduce the loading time for Polymer page which require lot of elements to be loaded.

So, Thinking about making elements loaded on demand, means once I use an element in the HTML code, if not loaded, it get loaded immediately.

Anybody have an idea how that can be done ?
Maybe some event is fired when unknown HTML element is being used ? So I can handle the loading using importHref() once that happen ?

Comment: I'd bet on vulcanizing all stuff in one big file and serving it zipped. Most likely all your application wieghs no more than Polymer+basic elts so user won't notice if you add extra 20-40K. But they will certainly notice delay before downloading each elt because of connection establishing time instantiation etc. 

Althoug it would be interesting to see some user-experiece studies on this.

Comment: I would suggest to vulcanize all your elements and load them only once. It can be done by vulcanize tool - https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize

Comment: Two options here. You can vulcanize your elements as stated in the comments above or you can lazy load them. There is a tutorial [here](https://aerotwist.com/blog/polymer-for-the-performance-obsessed/) that talks about creating an app with polymer including lazy loading the elements. There are a lot more out there too if you search for "polymer lazy load".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs, there isn't a standard way of optimize it, but you can use Vulcanize tool and test perfomance.

If you don't want load all your webcomponents in one request, you can vulcanize all the elements that you need in your initial page/view. So, you'll load a set of elements in one request and use them in your first page.

Then, you can implement a lazy loading consisting on adding link tags to head section for each webcomponent. By this way, load process isn't been made during browser's parse task, so isn't blocking.

Answer (score 1):

[iron-lazy-pages](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/iron-lazy-pages) may be useful to you:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route
    data="{{route_data}}"
    pattern="/:page"
    route="{{route}}"
></app-route>

<iron-lazy-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route_data.page}}">
    <x-page1 data-route="page1" data-path="demo/x-page1.html"></x-page1>
    <x-page2 data-route="page2" data-path="demo/x-page2.html"></x-page2>
    <section data-route="page3">
        My inline element.
    </section>
</iron-lazy-pages>
```

You can install with the following:

```
bower install --save TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages
```

Comment: Hmm, all my elements for all the pages are still loaded on first page load. I don't really get how this is supposed to work

Comment: I haven't used Polymer in over a year, but a quick search gave me this: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/polymer/lazy-imports